# C# mongoDB Data acquisition

Tags: c#, mongodb

guys. 
Immediately sorry for my English. 
I need help with a problem that I can not decide for several days myself.

I have a project in C # associated with mongoDB.
The user can create an account and create two characters for him.

Here's the character creation:

```
Character.Character character = new Character.Character
  {
    SocialClubName = player.socialClubName,
    Name = name,
    Surname = surname,
    RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now,
    LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now,
    RegistrationIp = player.address,
    CurrentIp = player.address
  };

  Characters.InsertOneAsync(character);
```

Character.cs

```
  public class Character
  {
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string SocialClubName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }    
    public string RegistrationIp { get; set; }
    public string CurrentIp { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
  }
```

And the problem is getting these data from the Database. I need to have global variables with the data of two characters.

Now it looks like this:

```
public static string Name { get; set; }
public static string Surname { get; set; }
public static string RegistrationIp { get; set; }
public static string CurrentIp { get; set; }
public static DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
public static DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }

public static async Task LoadCharacterData(Client player)
{
  var filter = new BsonDocument("NameOfTable", player.name);
  var characters = await DatabaseManager.Characters.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

  foreach (var character in characters)
  {
    Name = character.Name;
    Surname = character.Surname;
    RegistrationIp = character.RegistrationIp;
    CurrentIp = character.CurrentIp;
    RegistrationDate = character.RegistrationDate;
    LastLoginDate = character.LastLoginDate;
  }
}
```

It looks stupid, because I'm just starting to work with C#. I decided to use MongoDB, because I worked with it earlier with MeteorApp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example will overwrite the Name/SurName etc each time you read so you will only retrieve the last character.

You can create a User class and get those, something like this:

```
public class User 
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public string SurName{get;set;}
}

public static List<User> Users {get;set;}
public static async Task LoadCharacterData(Client player)
{
  //*Snip*
  foreach(var character in character)
    Users.Add(new User {Name = character.Name; SurName = character.Surname;}
}
```